# Is it possible to simulate a mining pool with localhost in windows?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, solo-mining

All I want to do is run the miner in CPU (without mining any real coins, no online pool, and no wallet) without connecting to any online miner. I tried using XMRig miner to do a localhost run but setting up the localhost to mimic a miner was not an option.

How can the localhost mimic the mining pool to miner so that the miner runs in the system?

Comment: you can search for mining-pool-software in the internet. as an alternativ you can implement the Stratum mining protocol but i think this is very difficult.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to mine?  Do you have a node that you are pointing to?

Comment: I am just trying to run the cryotonight algorithm in XMRig miner. I want to point to localhost as the mining pool but I am not sure what changes to make to local host so that the miner takes it as an input.